# Element with List (generic) - issues with equals

Tags: java, list, generics, equals

I had to program a doublyLinkedList and an ArrayList with methods that adds an element with its value and its frequency... If there is another element with the same value the frequency increases. Everything worked when it was at first declared as String, now I had to make it all generic so it can not just count Strings but also count ints, objects. Then I had to make an Object called Card (abstract) which generates just random `redCard` and `blackCard` objects that also get added to the list without issues.

My issue now is that it doesn't increase the frequency because the equals method doesn't work for the generic types. I now tried out several equals methods but none of them worked. Maybe there is some issues with my generic implementation?

```
package aufgabe4b;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author Nico
 * @since 05.05.23
 */
public class ArrayFrequencyTable<T> extends AbstractFrequencyTable<T> {
    private int size = 0;
    private Element<T> fqTable[];
    private final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 100;

    public ArrayFrequencyTable() {
        clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public final void clear() {
        fqTable = new Element[DEFAULT_SIZE];
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T e, int f) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (fqTable[i].getElement().equals(e)) {
                fqTable[i].addFrequency(f);
                moveToLeft(i);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (fqTable.length == size()) {
            fqTable = Arrays.copyOf(fqTable, 2 * size());
        }

        fqTable[size] = new Element<T>(e, f);
        size++;
        moveToLeft(size() - 1);
    }

    private void moveToLeft(int pos) {
                                        
        Element<T> e = fqTable[pos];
        int i = pos - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && e.getFrequency() > fqTable[i].getFrequency()) {
            fqTable[i + 1] = fqTable[i];
            i--;
        }
        fqTable[i + 1] = e;
    }

    /**
     * Liefert das Wort mit seiner HÃ¤ufigkeit zur&uuml;ck, das mit seiner
     * H&auml;ufigkeit an Position pos steht.
     * get(0) liefert das hÃ¤ufigste Wort zurÃ¼ck,
     * get(1) liefert das zweithÃ¤ufigste Wort zurÃ¼ck, usw.
     * 
     * @param pos Position.
     * @return Wort mit H&auml;ufigkeit oder null,
     *         falls die Tabelle weniger als pos-1 Elemente enth&auml;lt.
     */
    @Override
    public Element<T> get(int pos) {
        return fqTable[pos];
    }

    /*
     * Liefert die H&auml;ufigkeit des Worts w zur&uuml;ck.
     * Falls das Wort nicht vorkommt, wird 0 zur&uuml;ckgeliefert.
     * 
     * @param w Wort
     * 
     * @return H&auml;ufigkeit.
     */
    @Override
    public int get(T e) {
        for (Element<T> currentE : fqTable) {
            if (currentE != null && currentE.getElement().equals(e)) {
                return currentE.getFrequency();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
package aufgabe4b;

/**
 * Klasse fÃ¼r WÃ¶rter mit ihren HÃ¤ufigkeiten.
 * @author Nico
 * @since 05.05.23
 */
public class Element<T> {
    final private T e;
    private int freqency;
    
    /**
     * Konstruktor.
     * @param e Element
     * @param f H&auml;ufgkeit
     */
    public Element(T e, int f) {
        this.e = e;
        this.freqency = f;
    }

    /**
     * Liefert Wort zur&uuml;ck.
     * @return Wort
     */
    public T getElement() {
        return e;
    }

    /**
     * Liefert H&auml;ufgkeit zur&uuml;ck.
     * @return H&auml;ufgkeit
     */
    public int getFrequency() {
        return freqency;
    }
    
    /**
     * Addiert zur H&auml;ufgkeit f dazu.
     * @param f H&auml;ufgkeits&auml;nderung.
     */
    public void addFrequency(int f) {
        freqency += f;
    }

    /**
     * Liefert eine String-Darstellung zur&uuml;ck.
     * @return String-Darstellung.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return e + ":" + freqency;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Element){
            return ((Element)obj).get().equals(this.get());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For things like `this.get()` where `this` is an `Element`, `get` needs to be a method of `Element`.  It isn't.  Maybe you meant `this.e.get()`?

Comment: Or maybe you meant `this.getElement()`?

Comment: It's impossible to tell for sure due to the compilation error and the lack of the object definition for `Card`, but I suspect that `Card` does not correctly implement the [`Object.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method correctly.  This method is very specific about how it needs to be implemented, and if your data structure is working correctly with `String` object but not with arbitrary ones, that would be my guess as to the issue.  If you post that class, I can give you a better answer.